# Boosting a dryer vent with an inline booster attached to the main line with a wye

Tags: vent, dryer

Our dryer has an airflow sensor and is always warning us that the lint filter needs to be cleaned, even when it has just been cleaned.  This started after we moved it to a new house that has the vent about 7-8 ft above the floor.  I've improved it by changing to a rigid duct, but it is still an issue.  I can't move or enlarge the vent (it comes out a bit above ground level and comes through concrete).

So, I'd like to look at adding a dryer vent booster, which costs $200-$300.  What about adding an inline duct booster (which costs about $50, but is not designed to handle the lint) that draws from the room air, goes through a one way valve and then a wye into the dryer vent.

Has anyone tried that?  Do you think it would work ok?

Comment: What about a defective air flow sensor? Also, I may be missing something, but since my dryer does not have an airflow sensor and it works fine, if I was you I would probably disconnect it. I clean out our dryer vent once a year as part of routine maintenance and it has never had much stuff in it.

Answer (score 3):

That seems unlikely to work. A wye is not a venturi, so all that adding more air to the dryer vent is going to accomplish would be to further reduce flow from the dryer.

You are absolutely certain that the whole duct (and vent/exit) is clean and clear? You replaced the whole thing with rigid duct?